# Make room on my disk to install another OS

Tags: partition, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux on my HDD with the installer Option (right after the partition settings)

> Use entire disk space(beginners)

After installing Kali, I wanted to install 2 More OSs but now i can't repartition it anymore. What can I do without reinstalling?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pay more attention when taking a picture, you have half the information hidden by a menu. What are the other OSes? Most installers will handle the repartitioning.

Comment: I only wanted to show that the mode to increase|decrease the size is inactive. I can't make other partitions until i can decrease the size oft the Main partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unmount the drive before you can resize the partition. You will need to use a live CD/usb. Once you boot using the live CD you can repartition the drive.

If one of the OS that you are installing is windows you probably want to start with that and then add linux. While you can certainly do it in either order it tends to be easier to do windows first.